# Multiple downloads with Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob

I've been tasked in researching whether CT is capable of multiple downloads. For example, if someone adds a CD to their cart and two, separate MP3 files. When the person checks out will the two MP3 files be available for download or can only 1 file be available? I can probably run this through to test it out but thought I would see if anyone knows before spending a few hours testing.. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed have multiple downloads. You can use the `{exp:cart throb:download_file_form}` tag inside your loop for all the available downloads. There is a quick video that explains the download tag on Vimeo: [Download Tag Video](http://vimeo.com/37500649)